# dialogue box is dissapearing immediately after showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i am really bad in javascript,jquery..i have to make a page where course will be assigned to teacher,and if remaining credit of teacher is less than course credit that is being assigned to teacher then a dialogue box will open with yes and no option,if no is being chosen then dialogue box will close doing nothing,if yes then that course will be assigned to teacher and remaining credit of teacher will become minus.my problem is my dialogue box is closing immediately after showing,and also i have no clue how if yes is being chosen then value will be inserted in database,please help
this is my dialogue box code...

```
 $("#submit").click(function () {
                var courseCredit = $("#courseCredit").val();
                var remainingCredit = $("#remainingCredit").val();
                if (remainingCredit < courseCredit) {
                    //var dialog = $("#dialog");
                    $('<div title="Confirm Box"></div>').dialog({
                        open: function (event, ui) {
                            $(this).html("Yes or No question?");
                        },
                        autoOpen:true,
                        resizable: false,
                        width:'auto',
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            'Yes': function () {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            },
                            'No': function () {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        },
                        close: function (event,ui) {
                            $(this).remove();
                        }
                    });

                }


            });
```

this is html code...

```
  <form method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Department</label>
                        <select name="departmentId" id="departmentId">
                            <option value="">Select...</option>
                            @foreach (var department in departments)
                            {
                                <option value="@department.DepartmentId">@department.DepartmentName</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Teacher</label>
                        <select name="teacherId" id="teacherId">
                            <option value="0">Select...</option>
                        </select>

                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Credit to be taken</label>
                        @*@Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.)*@
                        <input type="text" name="creditTaken" id="creditTaken" readonly value="@Model.CreditTaken" />

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Remaining Credit</label>
                        <input type="text" name="remainingCredit" id="remainingCredit" readonly value="@Model.RemainingCredit" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Course Code</label>
                        <select name="courseId" id="courseId"></select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="courseName" id="courseName" readonly />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Credit</label>
                        <input type="email" name="courseCredit" id="courseCredit" readonly />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Assign"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td>
                        @if (ViewBag.ValidationMsg != null)
                        {
                            <p>@ViewBag.ValidationMsg</p>
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </form>
```

controller....

```
 public ActionResult CourseAssign(CourseAssign courseAssign)
    {

        var departments = _departmentManager.GetAllDepartments();

        ViewBag.Departments = departments;


            courseAssign.RemainingCredit = courseAssign.RemainingCredit - courseAssign.CourseCredit;
            int rowAffected = _teacherManager.InsertCourseAssign(courseAssign);

            if (rowAffected > 0)
            {
                ViewBag.ValidationMsg = "Successfull.";
                return View(courseAssign);
            }
            ViewBag.ValidationMsg = "This course is already assigned.";
            return View(courseAssign);
        //}
        //ViewBag.Checkmsg = "This course is already assigned.";
        //return View(courseAssign);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in your code the problem relies in the $("#submit") button click. As soon as you click the submit button you will see the pop up but the page is going to POST to your controller, which causes the page to reload (so you lose the pop up).

I suggest changing the type of the submit button, to "button" this will prevent the POST.

Then add an id to your form, so in your javascript code you can submit the form when needed using the instruction: $("#formid").submit();

So your code could be something like:

```
 $("#submit").click(function () {
            var courseCredit = $("#courseCredit").val();
            var remainingCredit = $("#remainingCredit").val();
            if (remainingCredit < courseCredit) {
                //var dialog = $("#dialog");
                $('<div title="Confirm Box"></div>').dialog({
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).html("Yes or No question?");
                    },
                    autoOpen:true,
                    resizable: false,
                    width:'auto',
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        'Yes': function () {
                            $("#formid").submit(); // submit to save in db
                        },
                        'No': function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    },
                    close: function (event,ui) {
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

And your html like:

```
<form method="POST" id="formid">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Department</label>
                    <select name="departmentId" id="departmentId">
                        <option value="">Select...</option>
                        @foreach (var department in departments)
                        {
                            <option value="@department.DepartmentId">@department.DepartmentName</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Teacher</label>
                    <select name="teacherId" id="teacherId">
                        <option value="0">Select...</option>
                    </select>

                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Credit to be taken</label>
                    @*@Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.)*@
                    <input type="text" name="creditTaken" id="creditTaken" readonly value="@Model.CreditTaken" />

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Remaining Credit</label>
                    <input type="text" name="remainingCredit" id="remainingCredit" readonly value="@Model.RemainingCredit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Course Code</label>
                    <select name="courseId" id="courseId"></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="courseName" id="courseName" readonly />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Credit</label>
                    <input type="email" name="courseCredit" id="courseCredit" readonly />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Assign"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td>
                    @if (ViewBag.ValidationMsg != null)
                    {
                        <p>@ViewBag.ValidationMsg</p>
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
```

Hope this helps!